# Read value of @ObservedObject only once without listening to changes

Tags: swiftui, observedobject

Suppose I have some environmental object that stores the states of a user being signed in or not;

```
class Account: ObservableObject{

    @Published var isSignedIn: Bool = false 

}
```

I want to conditional display a view if the user is signed in. So,
app loads -> RootView(). If user is signed In -> go to Profile, otherwise go to LoginScreen

```
struct RootView: View {

     @EnvironmentObject private var account: Account
     
     var body: some View {
    
     NavigationStackViews{

 // This is just a custom class to help display certain views with a transition animation 

    if account.isSignedIn{ // I only want to read this ONCE. Otherwise, when this value changes, my view will abruptly change views 
      ProfileView()

} else { SignInView() } 

}
}
    
}
```

Comment: So you only want to get the `isSignedIn` when `RootView` appears?

Comment: @George Yes, exactly

Answer (score 1):

Set a `@State` variable in [`onAppear(perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onappear(perform:)) of the current `isSignedIn` value. Then use that in the view body instead.

Code:

```
struct RootView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var account: Account
    @State private var isSignedIn: Bool?

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStackViews {
            if let isSignedIn = isSignedIn {
                if isSignedIn {
                    ProfileView()
                } else {
                    SignInView()
                }
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            isSignedIn = account.isSignedIn
        }
    }
}
```